# Parsing function application with Happy

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy

How would I parse something like

```
f x y
```

Into

```
APPLY (APPLY f x) y
```

using Happy? Right now I have a rule that says

```
%left APP
Expr : Expr Expr %prec APP { APPLY $1 $2 }
```

But that parses the above as

```
APPLY f (APPLY x y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode left/right associativity using grammar rules.

For example, have a look at this basic lambda calculus parser:

https://github.com/ghulette/haskell-parser-examples/blob/master/src/HappyParser.y

The operative productions are:

```
Expr : let VAR '=' Expr in Expr    { App (Abs $2 $6) $4 }
     | '\\' VAR '->' Expr          { Abs $2 $4 }
     | Form                        { $1 }

Form : Form '+' Form               { Binop Add $1 $3 }
     | Juxt                        { $1 }

Juxt : Juxt Atom                   { App $1 $2 }
     | Atom                        { $1 }

Atom : '(' Expr ')'                { $2 }
     | NUM                         { Num $1 }
     | VAR                         { Var $1 }
```

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is not satisfactory.

The correct way of solving this problem is:

```
%nonassoc VAR LPAREN -- etc...
%nonassoc APP

Expr : Expr Expr %prec APP { APPLY $1 $2 }
```

That is:

- Adding a ghost precedence token called `APP`, and no need to make it `left` or `right` since it won't be relevant, so you can keep it `nonassoc` to not get the wrong intuition that it matters
- Marking your `Expr` rule with `%prec APP` like  you did
- **and most importantly and often forgotten**, you need to give all tokens that may appear as the first token of an `Expr` production a precedence lower than that of `APP`, usually achieved by listing them somewhere above, either with `left`, `right`, or `nonassoc` for the ones that don't associate

The reason why your trial failed is probably that you missed the last step.

The reason why the last step is needed is that the algorithm, in deciding whether to shift the next token or to reduce the `APP` rule, will compare the precedence of the `APP` rule with the precedence of the incoming token. And by default, tokens that you don't mention have high precedence. So when faced with:

```
Expr Expr . LPAREN VAR RPAREN
```

for instance, it would compare the precedence of the `APP` rule (to reduce), with the precedence of `LPAREN` (to shift), and unless you set it up correctly, it will shift, and do the wrong thing.

---

Staging your grammar is just ugly and unpleasant.

Comment: This has just helped me. Thank you.

Comment: @paulotorrens if you want even deeper explanations, I wrote a blog post about this issue: https://ptival.github.io/2017/05/16/parser-generators-and-function-application/